# unable to share cache between VMS created on openstack in order to create side channel

Tags: caching, virtual-machine, openstack, kvm

To show the cross channel attack we need to share the cache among the virtual machines created on the same physical host.
 Using openstack i am able to create VMs on the same physical host using KVM hypervisor but  unable to share the cache.

If I use xen hypervisor instead of KVM, will it help? 
How do I make sure cache is shared between the VMS?
Need some guidelines regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok if you use either KVM or xen depending on your system design and hardware required .

To add on Cache will be shared once you spawn the VMs. Please check your cpu specs for L1 ,L2 and L3 cache . Also check VM allocation as to how much RAM is it consuming while creating a VM instance !!!! The question you posted is very wide !!!